# Loading screen after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm doing a RoR page and after a form the next page takes a lot to load, so i wish to have a loading page between the submit and the next page

```
<%= form_tag(next_path, :id => 'myform') do %>
    <%= label_tag "My data" %>
    <%= text_field "name", "", placeholder: "Your name" %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Next' %>
<% end %>
```

Submit

```
Loading... //Here display the loading screen
```

A lot time after displays the next page

```
"Hello to the next page User"
```

**EDIT**

The loading screen should be in the start page, because the next page does a lot of sql queries and doesn't take javascript functions until it finishes

Solutions from rails to jquery are welcome

Comment: takes a lot to submit (stays in the first page until submission is complete) or to load the next page?

Comment: preferly stays in the page and display the loading stuff, because the next page does a lot of sql queries, miss that in the description, i'm going to edit it

Comment: the way I'd do it is using `submit` [event](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) and display a popup with loading info and an overlay behind it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy. Add a hidden "loading" message to your layout (or just the forms that submit to slow loading pages)

```
<div id="slow_warning" style="display:none">
  Loading...
</div>
```

define a JavaScript function that shows the loading message

```
function show_slow_warning() {
  $("#slow_warning").show();
}
```

then call that function whenever you trigger navigation to a slow page. You can do this with an `onclick` handler for links or `onsubmit` handler for forms. If you want to be really tricky (and clean) you can assign the handlers unobtrusively.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.link_to_slow_page').click(function(){
    show_slow_warning();
  });
});
```